# Title: Error Opening MODFLOW6 CBC File (generated by flopy) in ModelMuse

Tags: python, output, visualization, modeling, flopy

I'm encountering an issue while trying to open a MODFLOW6 Cell-By-Cell (CBC) output file in ModelMuse. The error message I'm receiving is as follows. I'm using Flopy to generate the MODFLOW6 model and associated output files. The issue appears to be related to a mismatch between the dataset and the model grid. I would appreciate any guidance or insights on how to resolve this issue.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UIxO6.png)
I've successfully run a MODFLOW6 simulation using Flopy, and the CBC output file was generated without any errors.
I'm using ModelMuse to visualize and analyze the simulation results.
The error occurs when I attempt to open the CBC file within ModelMuse.

Answer (score -1):

The error message suggests a mismatch in the grid dimensions between the CBC file and the grid configuration within ModelMuse. To resolve this issue, you should ensure that the grid defined in ModelMuse exactly matches the grid used in the MODFLOW6 simulation (which was set up using Flopy).

Here's how you can go about it:

**Load existing grid**: If you have an existing grid file (e.g., a .dis file) that matches your MODFLOW6 simulation, you should load this into ModelMuse first before attempting to open the CBC file.

**Create matching grid in ModelMuse**: If you do not have an existing grid file or if the existing one does not match, you'll need to manually set up a new grid in ModelMuse that matches the grid specifications used in your Flopy model. This includes the number of layers, rows, columns, and the cell sizes.

**Verify Flopy script**: Go back to your Flopy script and check the grid specifications (nlay, nrow, ncol, cell spacing, etc.) to ensure they match what you're setting up in ModelMuse.

Once you've ensured that the grid dimensions match, you should be able to successfully load the CBC file in ModelMuse without encountering the error. It's crucial that the grid setup is done prior to loading any output files in ModelMuse to avoid any dimension mismatch errors.